# Dummy Variable Column Head not found?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dummy-variable

I am attempting logistic regression for a class, and I got stuck on something very strange, I haven't seen this error before. I am a complete python noob so I'd appreciate being very specific in details. Please dumb it down for me!

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cancer=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\kpic1\\Desktop\\Spring 2019\\IDIS 450\\Second exam\\Provided documents\\Cancer_Research_Q2.csv')
cancer.set_index('PatientID', inplace=True)
cancer=pd.get_dummies(cancer, columns=['Class'], drop_first=True)
cancer.head()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
cancer.rename(columns={'Class_Malignant':'Malignant'}, inplace=True)
cancer.head()
```

The table that is returned shows the dummy variable on the very end still being named "Class_Malignant."

When I try to print just this column using

```
print(cancer['Class_Malignant'])
```

I get the following long error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Class_Malignant'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-09d1356e98ac> in <module>
      1 #for some reason, "Class_Malignant" is not registering as a column head?
----> 2 print(cancer['Class_Malignant'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
-> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
   2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2491             cache[item] = res

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Class_Malignant'
```

From what I can tell from this, the column name "Class_Malignant" does not exist in the data set? Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Based on assumption you have renamed column name `Class_Malignant` to `Malignant` so try cancer['Malignant']

Comment: Yes, but when i use cancer.head() to show the top 5 rows of the data, the column name is still Class_Malignant

Comment: @piccolom5, are you sure that even after the line `cancer.rename(columns={'Class_Malignant':'Malignant'}, inplace=True)
`, `cancer.head()` shows the column name unchanged? If that's true, the rename operation is failing, likely because the column's exact name is different from `Class_Malignant`. Maybe it contains trailing or leading spaces?

Comment: I also thought that as well, but I tried just copying and pasting it straight from the column name, rather than typing it, to overcome that. Nothing changed. So essentially the rename is failing because it doesn't recognize a column as having the title 'Class_Malignant', but when I try to use print('cancer[Class_Malignant]'), while copying and pasting the 'Class_Malignant' part from the top of the column when i use cancer.head(), I get the long error message above.